# Solution for "MySQL server has gone away"

Tags: php, mysql

> Warning: mysql_query(): MySQL server has gone away in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mk_buktyas\siapuas\menu\home.php on line 90
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): Error reading result set's header in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mk_buktyas\siapuas\menu\home.php on line 90

MySQL server has gone away

Comment: also post your code.

Comment: This error usually means your query has crashed the MySQL server. But if it happens in exactly 60 seconds, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644432/mysql-server-has-gone-away-in-exactly-60-seconds?s=1|0.0000

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801794/mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Answer (score 0):

First of all please post your error with code.But I have made answer because your error is looks like due to the use of `mysql` extension.So use `mysqli` extension.Or you can also use php data objects `pdo` exttension.

so replace your code

```
mysql_query($connection,$sql);
```

To

```
mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
```

Where `$connection` is database connection object and `$sql` is your sql query that you want to execute.

Note: `mysql` extension is deprecated and removed from `php7`.So here you have to use `mysqli` stands for mysql-improved.

Comment: The connection isn't included in the older, deprecated `mysql_*` extension.

Comment: Changing the database API probably won't fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

IT IS SURE THAT YOUR ISSUE WILL BE RESOLVED

1. JUST GO TO XAMPP-CONTROL, CLICK ON THAT, YOU WILL FIND CONFIGURE BESIDE MYSQL SERVICE. CLICK ON THAT ON MY.INI FILE/ YOU CAN FOLLOW THIS PATH "XAMPP/MYSQL/BIN/MY.INI"
2. NOW SEARCH WITH THIS "max_allowed_packet" ON MY.INI. YOU WILL GET THE VALUE 1M, JUST SET THIS VALUE TO 1000M
3. NOW GO TO XAMPP-CONTROL[EXECUTABLE FILE]/SERVICE/MYSQL AND RESTART THE MYSQL

Comment: Please do not spam capital letters.