# Fixing Connection timed out in PHP way (on shared server)

Tags: php, mysql

I often got error message, and the Connection timed out duration is from minutes to hours.

```
mysqli::query(): MySQL server has gone away

mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out
```

I try to do same settings from similar questions in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801794/mysql-server-has-gone-away) and [MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html)

But `mysql.connect_timeout` and `default_socket_timeout` are not available settings in phprc on my host(DreamHost)

`SET GLOBAL statements` in PhpMyAdmin is also not allowed, so I cannot set `max_allowed_packet` on my host(DreamHost)

I already set in phprc

```
memory_limit = 128M //The max available value on my host(DreamHost)
```

I also put these codes in the beginning of .php file(I think this is in vain because they are not available settings in phprc)

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 18000);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 18000);
//18000 a little bit crazy I know
```

> Are there anything I can try to avoid `Connection timed out` and
>   `MySQL server has gone away` ? In PHP way?

---

How about add this in my .php file? Whenever `Connection timed out` happened then kill php

```
<?php
if(preg_match("/Connection timed out/", mysqli_connect_error()) ){
    exec ( "killall -9 php55.cgi" );
    //This won't work, when My php exec kill command, I get "`500 Internal Server Error`" from browser
}
?>
```

---

I guess sometimes table `marked as crashed and should be repaired` is due to  `Connection timed out`? Because in PhpMyAdmin table status always OK.

Comment: you can use this code
set_time_limit(0); put this code top on the file then i think it will work

Comment: What kind of application do you have? Is it a `cli` app?

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam I will put this code and observe how it goes, thanks!

Comment: @shukshin.ivan Do you mean user use cli app to connect our website?

Comment: `set_time_limit` is for script execution, not for mysql.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan you are right, it won't work~

Answer (score 0):

please try this code, i think it will fulfill your requirement

```
set_time_limit(0);   
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout','0');   
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
```