# mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, operationalerror

I got this error when I execute my query

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in de
faulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801794/mysql-server-has-gone-away), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338051/2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)  and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away) and [this  one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

I read the [Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html) and I know that I got this error because `image_name` in  my query is too large

> You can also get these errors if you send a query to the server that
>   is  too large.

I set a limite for the length of my variable

```
image_name = (image_name[:180]) if len(image_name) > 180 else image_name
cmd = "UPDATE `banners` SET `checked` =  '1',`local_dir` = %s , `image_name` = %s  WHERE  `unique_id` = %s "
cursor.execute(cmd,[local_addr,image_name,unique_id])
```

And I set also   `max_allowed_packet` in `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

Do you have any idea how can I avoid this error?

Comment: I have the same problem. did you find the answer?