# Executing mysqli_stmt->execute() causes "MySQL server has gone away" error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Okay. This is a weird one. First, here's the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: MySQL server has gone away in database.php:84
>       Stack trace:
>           #0 database.php(84): mysqli_stmt->execute()

According to other StackOverflow articles such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801794/mysql-server-has-gone-away), that error, `MySQL server has gone away` means that either:

- The mysqli object is being reused without being closed first (nope, definitely not)
- The connection timeout variable was too small on the MySQL server's end
- The maximum packet size variable is too small

However, I have set the timeout and the maximum packet size variable to their maximum values, and the query is simply selecting from an empty table. There's no reason why either of those should be a problem. I also verified from Python-- the server can be connected to and queries should be able to be executed. It even works fine from phpMyAdmin.

On the PHP documentation for [`mysqli_stmt::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php), it says this regarding the error:

[image: php docs screenshot]

- I'm using *mysqlnd* on Linux, and it's not supposed to give this error when the statement is longer than `max_allowed_packet`
- I have already mentioned how I have set `max_allowed_packet` to the variable's maximum value.

If you would like for me to give more information such as my SQL server or PHP configuration, let me know what you need.

One article I read said to use `mysqli->ping()` to check how the connection's doing, and it appears to be fine until I call `mysqli_stmt->execute()`.

I'm fairly certain it's a problem with my implementation-- I tried reinstalling the web server and the MySQL server, switching PHP versions, and I even tried switching hosts. But despite my attempts to fix this, I continue to get the error.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 3000);
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 3000);

    /* define the database class */
    class Database {
        public $host = 'localhost';
        public $name = '';
        public $user = '';
        public $pass = '';

        private $mysqli;

        /* constructor function, inits the database connection */
        function __construct($chost, $cname, $cuser, $cpass) {
            $this->host = $chost;
            $this->name = $cname;
            $this->user = $cuser;
            $this->pass = $cpass;

            mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
            $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->getHost(), $this->getUsername(), $this->getPassword(), $this->getName());
        }

        /* closes the connection to the database */
        function close() {
            return $this->getMySQLi()->close();
        }

        /* returns a query object for the given parameters */
        function query($query, $type='', ...$params) {
            $statement = $this->getMySQLi()->prepare($query);


            if(strlen($type) != 0) {
                // bind parameters to query
                $statement->bind_param($type, ...$params);
            }

            /*
             * stackoverflow readers: this the debug code
             * I mentioned to check the connection
             *
             */
            if ($this->getMySQLi()->ping()) {
                printf ("Our connection is ok!\n");
            } else {
                printf ("Error: %s\n", $this->getMySQLi()->error);
            }

            return new Query($statement);
        }

        /* getter functions */

        function getMySQLi() {
            return $this->mysqli;
        }

        function getHost() {
            return $this->host;
        }

        function getName() {
            return $this->name;
        }

        function getUsername() {
            return $this->user;
        }

        function getPassword() {
            return $this->pass;
        }
    }

    /* define the query class */
    class Query {
        private $statement;
        private $result;

        /* constructor, sets variables and stuff */
        function __construct($statement) {
            $this->statement = $statement;
        }

        /* executes the statement */
        function execute() {
            $status = $this->getStatement()->execute();
            $this->result = $this->getStatement()->get_result();

            return $status;
        }

        /* closes the statement */
        function close() {
            return $this->getStatement()->close();
        }

        /* returns the number of results */
        function countRows() {
            return $this->getResult()->num_rows;
        }

        /* getter functions */

        /* returns the statement object */
        function getStatement() {
            return $this->statement;
        }

        /* returns the result object */
        function getResult() {
            return $this->result;
        }

        function getRow() {
            return $this->getResult()->fetch_assoc();
        }

        /* returns the result in an array */
        function getRows() {
            $rows = array();
            while($row = $this->getRow()) {
                $rows[] = $row;
            }

            return $rows;
        }
    }
?>
```

So. My question is, is there a problem with my implementation? How can the problem be mitigated? Is it a problem with the SQL server or PHP?

**Edit:** Here's how I'm using the Database class (`getConnection()` simply returns a new Database instance)

```
function getUsers() {
    $query = getConnection()->query('SELECT * FROM `users`');
    $query->execute();
    return $query->getRows();
}
```

Comment: where did you use these class in which it caused this error? I copied and pasted your code and tried it, it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Wreigh I edited the question and added the code that used this class at the bottom. If that works for you too, may I ask what PHP version, webserver, and modules you're using? Thanks!

Comment: php 7.1.7 and i just used php's built it server. This is how I've used it. `$a = new Database('localhost', 'test_suites', 'root', '');
$b = $a->query("SELECT * FROM test_suites");
$b->execute();`

Comment: oh, sorry. I've commented `mysqli_report()` that why it worked! lol wait.

Comment: can you try changing `MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL` to `MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR`?

Comment: now I was able to replicate the problem with this. `$a = new Database('localhost', 'test_suites', 'root', '');
$j = $a->query("SELECT * FROM test_suites");
$a = null;
$j->execute();` I've set `$a` to `null`. I've remember what I read a while ago that when a *resource* has no references it will be garbage collected (there are exceptions to this, read php doc). are you sure that your **mysqli** resources still has references before you've executed your statement?

Comment: np, it outputs: `Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in database.php on line 84` (line # is different in the code I published here because of comments and stuff I added in before publishing).

Comment: @Wreigh No way. I think you just found the solution to this bug, which I have spent a ton of time trying to fix. I can't believe it, but it's working now. All I did is pass the Database object through the constructor of query and save it in a variable (then check if null before executing), then boom, it works. Thanks a ton! If you post an answer, I'll mark it as correct (once it lets me)

Comment: Please take a look at my answer updated by @Your Common Sense. It is useful, since you only have one connection all through out your script, in contrast with opening a connection for every query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I now know what is causing the problem! I wish I'm right.

```
function getUsers() {
    // here you are creating a Database instance,
    // but you've left it in the air, because you just retrieved `query` from it.
    $query = getConnection()->query('SELECT * FROM `users`');
    // at this point, there are already NO Database instance,
    // because you have no reference of it.
    // thus what I've read about resources being garbage collected
    // will now apply here.
    $query->execute();
    // this will fail, indeed, Mysql has gone away!
    return $query->getRows();
}
```

You should, at least save the connection to another variable.

```
$conn = getConnection();
$query = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM `user`');
$query->execute();
return $query->getRows();
```

But as a proper solution you must keep a single connection alive through the whole script execution and use it for all queries.

Comment: Thanks a ton, you have no idea how happy I am that this is finally working!

Comment: you're welcome. happy for it too, i was able to solve a problem which i'm not very familiar with xD

Comment: ok. to answer your question, based from what he has provided, he is creating a query using `$query = getConnection()->query('SELECT * FROM `user`')`. Since `getConnection()` as what he have said creates a new instance of `Database`, after the chain call to `query`, reference to that new instance is now gone (since nothing ever caught it). Well, if my memory serves me right, resources in php are garbage collected if there are no references to it (with the exception of persistent database links). when no one caught the Database instance, underlying mysqli was gone.

Comment: btw, he had a different approach than what I've posted. This is what he has done even before I've posted this answer. *All I did is pass the Database object through the constructor of query and save it in a variable (then check if null before executing)*